# Python JSON prints the same data twice (only in one case)

Tags: python, json

A json prints the same data multiple times when called another time. It seems good on the first time but each next call makes it print only a part of JSON-contained string multiple times and only then the rest of it.

Python code

```
with open("src/pages/userguide_sections.json", mode="rb") as f:
userguide_sections = json.load(f)

try:
section = int(input("1 - General idea about passwords\n2 - How can somebody get your password?\\n3 - How to create secure passwords\n4 - Return to main menu\\nUser input: "))
except ValueError:
print("Please enter a valid query, your last input is not a valid query")
pause()
continue

# Choise

        match section:
            case 1:
                os.system("cls")
                print(userguide_sections["section1"])
                pause()
            case 2:
                os.system("cls")
                print(userguide_sections["section2"])
                pause()
            case 3:
                os.system("cls")
                print(userguide_sections["section3"])
                pause()
            case 4:
                os.system("cls")
                print("[RETURN TO MAIN MENU]")
                return
            case _:
                os.system("cls")
                print(f"Please enter a valid query, {section} is not a valid query")
                pause()
                continue
```

JSON

```
{
...
"section2": "A criminal can break your passwords in various ways. Let's cover some most popular of them.\n\n1. Using vulnerabilities in your software.\\nIn the code of your software could be some flaws. A criminal can use those flaws to inject malicious code into your programs to extract information from them. To avoid that you must use antivirus software and update in regularly. In the similar way, your data could be intercepted if you transfer it using insecure channel. There's a device called 'sniffer' that allows individuals to monitor all traffic in the network. In the 1990's it was widely used to capture logins and password sent to websites using insecure channels like WEP. Nowadays most of us use WPA, a lot more secure channel. So if you want your data to stay secure – use only secure channels and don't trust public wi-fi networks.\n\n2. Brute-force.\nBrute-force is a way to guess your password using exhaustive search. A criminal enters different combinations until he gains access to the system. The main way to protect yourself from this type of attacks is to use strong passwords and change them at least once a month. The longer your password is, the longer it takes to guess it because there's a lot more combinations. The bare minimum to the password length is 14 (if your password contains digits, punctuation symbols, lowercase and uppercase letters). This password will take 34k years to guess. Pretty secure, huh? But you have to keep in mind that on average it takes to try only half the combinations to guess your password, so always divide that time by two.\n\n3. Social engeneering.\nA criminal could deceive you by pretending to be an administrator or any other important man. You could receive a message, which tells you that there's suspicious activity on your account and you must provide your login and password in a response letter as soon as possible. You have to remember that officials NEVER ask users their data. Criminals can also create web-pages looking exactly like official ones and try to force you to login on that site. You must never login to any service using provided links or the data you have inputted will go straight to the criminal's mailbox.",
...
}
```

When I try to print section1 or section3 everything seems fine, and on the first try of printing section2 I get good result, but on the next try I get a bug.
Screenshots included

Section2 bad print on the second try, bad print highlighted

[image: Section2 bad print on the second try, bad print highlighted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turnes out, the VS Code console is just unable to properly diplay anything that is too big for the console window. If you expand the terminal tab enough for the message to be displayed without vertical scroll tab appearing, you will gain consistent, good results. Also if you just use windows's cmd, you will see that this code works fine all the time.